# python3: TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

I am very new to python.
I am trying to run a simple code with a 2d list. But I'm getting an error:
"TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable". Can anyone please help me with how to solve this? Or what is wrong with the code.

```
import sys
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

max_event = 1000000
a_bin = 10  # number each bin from 0-->10 where cumulant calculation will be done

# Define 2D array for [ bin, here 0->10][proton in each bin]
pArray = (() for nn in range(a_bin))
neve = (0 for mm in range(a_bin))

for ii in range(0, max_event):

    _a = np.random.randint(10)
    _b = np.random.randint(120)

    if ii % 1000 == 0:
        print(ii, _a, _b)

    for j in range(0, 10):
        if _a == j:
            pArray[j].append(_b)
            neve[j] += 1


print("filling done!")

for k in range(0, a_bin):

    mu2 = stats.mstats.moment(pArray[k], moment=2)
    mu4 = stats.mstats.moment(pArray[k], moment=4)

    print('serial = %d, mu_2 = %f , mu_4 = %f, event = %d' %
          (k, mu2, mu4, neve[k]))
    # print k, neve[k], c1[k], c2[k], c3[k], c4[k], c5[k], c6[k]

print("calculation done!")
```

Here is the output I am getting:

> 0 9 18 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "calcumuBin.py", line
>   23, in 
>       pArray[j].append(_b) TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Generators *aren't* subscriptable. If you want to index `pArray`, make it a list instead.

Comment: `pArray` isn't a `list` (and definitely not an array). You used a *generator expression*, which created a *generator object*. Don't do that. If you are very new to python, you shouldn't use these more advanced constructs without fully understanding them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the pArray to be a list of lists that will prevent you from getting the `TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable`

```
pArray = [[] for nn in range(a_bin)]
neve = [0 for mm in range(a_bin)]
```